# Count unique field when another field is all NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with three columns, which can contain duplicate rows

1. org - int NULL
2. id - int NULL
3. complete - bit NULL

So I might have data like so:

```
org | id | complete
-------------------
1   |  1 | 1
1   |  2 | NULL
1   |  2 | 1
1   |  3 | 1
2   |  3 | 1
2   |  4 | 1
2   |  4 | NULL
```

I want to get a count of all distinct `id` by `org`.  That's easy enough to do with a `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` expression.  Where I'm running into trouble now is I also want a count of all distinct `id` where any of the `complete` values isn't 1.

So from the above I'd want this output:

```
org | distinct id | distinct incomplete id
------------------------------------------
  1 |   3         |  1
  2 |   2         |  1
```

So for org 2, because `id` of 4 included a NULL value, then I can't count id 4 as fully complete, thus just `id` 3 is complete, thus resulting in a 1 in the `distinct incomplete id` column.  So I don't know how to fill in the ???? part of the below query.

```sql
SELECT org, COUNT(DISTINCT id) TotalPeople, ???? IncompletePeople
FROM table
GROUP BY org
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Org INT,
    Id INT,
    Complete BIT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(1,1,1),(1,2,NULL),(1,2,1),(1,3,1),(2,3,1),(2,4,1),(2,4,NULL)

SELECT
    Org,
    DistinctId = COUNT(DISTINCT Id),
    DistinctIncompleteId = SUM(CASE Complete WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    FROM @T
        GROUP BY Org
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way

```
    create table #temptable ( org int, id int, comp int )
    Go

    insert into #temptable ( org, id, comp )
    values ( 1,1,1)
    ,( 1, 2, null)
    ,( 1, 2, 1)
    ,( 1, 3, 1)
    ,( 2, 3, 1)
    ,( 2, 4, null)
    ,( 2, 4, 1)

    select d.org, d.DistinctId, f.incompleteId from (
    select COUNT (distinct id) as DistinctId , org from #temptable  group by org) as d full outer join (
    select COUNT (distinct id) as incompleteId , org from #temptable where comp is null group by org) as f on d.org=f.org 


    go

    drop table #temptable
```

Answer (score 0):

Group it by "org" and by "complete". Then put HAVING complete=1. Hope the code below helps you:

```
SELECT org, COUNT(id) TotalPeople, complete
FROM table
GROUP BY org,complete
HAVING complete=1 (complete IS NULL *for incomplete*)
```